# Unhandled exception [0]: Call to undefined function get_sql_for_list_inquiry()

Tags: php

got a problem sql statement it working on my `customer_inquiry` but when I write new sql statement `list_inquiry` gets

```
    $sql = get_sql_for_list_inquiry(get_post('TransAfterDate'), get_post('TransToDate'),
        get_post('customer_id'), get_post('filterType'));
```

> Unhandled exception [0]: Call to undefined function

Comment: Do you have a function called `get_sql_for_list_inquiry()` and is it included properly before you're trying to use it? Also, the error you're getting is unrelated to any sql-statement and mysql/sql/sqlite so those tags should be removed.

Comment: tell us more about it. the code I mean. this error is genrally generated when it cannnot find the function.